# Exception handling in oop PHP not working

Tags: php, oop, exception

I am very new to object oriented PHP and trying some basic examples to get good hand on oop php. I have simple exmaple above in which i am trying to learn exception handling and generate an exception error message when age is greater than 20 but not working.

```
<?php
interface read_methods 
{
    public function read_age($age);
}
abstract class  person 
{ 
    var $gender;
    var $animal;
    var $birds;
    abstract function group($group);
    function people($value)
    {
        $this->gender=$value;
    }
    function animals($value)
    {
        $this->animal=$value;
    }
    function bird($value)
    {
        $this->birds=$value;
    }
}

class behaviour extends person implements read_methods
{
    var $nonhuman;
    function get_all()
    {
        return $this->people();
        return $this->animals();
        return $this->bird();
    }
    function non_human($nonhuman)
    {
        return $this->alien=$nonhuman;
    }
    function read_age($age)
    {       
        try {
            $this->age=$age;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            if ($age > 20)
            {
                throw new Exeption("age exceeds",$age, $e->getMessage());
            }
        }               
    }
    function group($group)
    {
        return $this->group=$group;
    }
}

$doerte=new behaviour();  
$doerte ->people(array('male','female'));
$doerte ->animals(array('fish','whale'));
$doerte ->bird(array('parrot','crow'));
$doerte->non_human('alien');
$doerte->read_age('23');
$doerte->group('living_things');
//$doerte->__autoload();
print_r($doerte);
?>
```

Comment: It helps if you spell `Exception` correctly.... it isn't `Exeption`.... but why are you throwing it inside a catch block? Your try/catch should be in the main code, not in the read_age method which should simply throw the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you throw the exception at the wrong place.

If something is invalid you need to throw. That belongs to the try part. The catch part is used to handle the exception.

Think of it that way: you trow an exception if you programm has to yell out for help since it doesnt know what to do with data (try). The exception block should be used to take care of that cry for help

```
function read_age($age)
{       
    try {
        if($age > 20) {
            throw new Exception('Too old!');
        }
        $this->age=$age;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'There has been an error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your PHP error logs? Might be the misspelled "Exeption" which should be "Exception" => new \Exception(...

@Debflav: sorry for the double post. your answere hasn't shown up on my screen at the time

Comment: hi actually in question i made that mistake but in coding i wrote correctly as "exeption" :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create an exception when age exceeds 20? Here could be a solution (partial code):

```
/* ... */
function read_age($age)
    {       
        if ($age > 20) {
            throw new Exception("age exceeds, shoulw be less than 20");
        } else {
            $this->age=$age;
        }
    }
/* ... */

try {
    $doerte=new behaviour();  
    $doerte ->people(array('male','female'));
    $doerte ->animals(array('fish','whale'));
    $doerte ->bird(array('parrot','crow'));
    $doerte->non_human('alien');
    $doerte->read_age('23');
    $doerte->group('living_things');
    echo "It's all right";
    print_r($doerte);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Something went wrong: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: sory ur code is working but i guess its not correct just fetching all the objects inside try block ?

Comment: Ideally you should put only risky operations to the try{} block. And try to put as low as possible code there. I just copied your code assuming that in your case object creation is risky operation. You can keep $doerte->read_age('23'); inside try{} and it will work either.

Comment: yes but as your exeption message suggests only for age object so if any error occurs then it will generate the same exeption right ?

Comment: You can add throwing exception to any setter. For example add some verification and throw new Exception('Wrong group') to behaviour::group(), then you'll see corresponding message in catch block.